# IPv6 packet header manipulation

Tags: sockets, networking, go, ipv6

I need to inspect and modify the IPv6 extension headers. So I set up a raw socket to listen for all IP packets on the local address.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    c, err := net.ListenIP("ip6:tcp", &net.IPAddr{
        IP:   net.IPv6loopback,
        Zone: "",
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        numRead, ipaddr, err := c.ReadFromIP(buf)
        log.Print(numRead, ipaddr, err)
        log.Printf("% X\n", buf[:numRead])
    }
}
```

I tried all the `Read*()` methods on the connection but it seems like they just return the payload without the header.
So my question is: **How can I access the IPv6 header of a packet?**

Comment: One thing to note is that IPv6 extension headers are rarely used, and, unfortunately, many ISPs in a path will either block or strip extension headers because they can be used for attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raw sockets with IPv6 are different compared to IPv4. Relevant for your case is [RFC 3542](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3542). Note:

> Another difference from IPv4 raw sockets is **that complete packets (that is, IPv6 packets with extension headers) cannot be sent or received using the IPv6 raw sockets API.** Instead, ancillary data objects are used to transfer the extension headers and hoplimit information, as described in Section 6.  **Should an application need access to the complete IPv6 packet, some other technique**, such as the datalink interfaces BPF or DLPI, must be used.

---

You can find this out on your own. By running (and strace'ing) your program on my box for every packet I get:

```
recvfrom(3, "\x45\x00\x00\x3c\x6a\x7d...
               ^^
```

This means IP version = 4, IHL = 5 (20 bytes).

When I try the same thing with IPv6 (i.e. your original code), I get something different every time:

```
recvfrom(3, "\xc6\x22\x00\x50\x4d
```

In this case every time the kernel is returning stuff starting directly with TCP (in this case the port is `50722`, i.e `0xC622`).

Another interesting part should be noted in the [sources](https://golang.org/src/net/iprawsock_posix.go?s=1951:2010#L58):

```
switch sa := sa.(type) {
case *syscall.SockaddrInet4:
    addr = &IPAddr{IP: sa.Addr[0:]}
    n = stripIPv4Header(n, b)
case *syscall.SockaddrInet6:
    addr = &IPAddr{IP: sa.Addr[0:], Zone: zoneToString(int(sa.ZoneId))}
}
```

The header is stripped manually **for IPv4** but not for IPv6: for IPv6 there is nothing to remove.

---

Note, there are mechanisms that will return extra information (but by no means the whole packet). For example the `IPV6_RECVPKTINFO` socket option will give you access to:

```
struct in6_pktinfo {
    struct in6_addr ipi6_addr;    /* src/dst IPv6 address */
    unsigned int    ipi6_ifindex; /* send/recv interface index */
};
```

Similar options exist for the routing header option, hop limit etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already noticed the part in the sources where the header is stripped but didn't know the reason for it. So i guess it's just not possible to do with the `net` package?!

Comment: @fl0cke I think the net package is not sufficient here. You might get away with the Linux-specific [`PF_PACKET`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html) or BPF (available on a number of Unixes).